# Latex 2x2 figure(using subfigure) in two-column article

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Can someone please help me to create 2x2 figures using subfigure in two-column article ?

Comment: Can you provide an example - ie. a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I recommend having a look over at [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com). Especially [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196481/problem-on-subfigure-2x2/196483#196483) where a 2x2 figure layout is given.